# Rendering Images from a Json Result (Google Image API) PHP

Tags: php, json, image-processing, rendering, search-engine

I can read image search results from the Google Search API, which are stored in a JSON result, an extract from which is below, showing the first result when searching for ***"elephant"***:

Storing the Json in $js: `$js = json_decode($data,true);`

var_dump the json: `var_dump($js);`

```
["items"]=> array(10) 
 { [0]=> array(9) 
 { 
   ["kind"]=> string(19) "customsearch#result" 
   ["title"]=> string(66) "African Elephants, African Elephant Pictures, African Elephant ..." 
   ["htmlTitle"]=> string(94) "African Elephants, African Elephant Pictures, African Elephant ..." 
   ["link"]=> string(105) "http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/004/cache/african-elephant_435_600x450.jpg" 
   ["displayLink"]=> string(30) "animals.nationalgeographic.com" 
   ["snippet"]=> string(62) "African Elephants, African Elephant Pictures, African Elephant" 
   ["htmlSnippet"]=> string(83) "African Elephants, African Elephant Pictures, African Elephant" 
   ["mime"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" 
   ["image"]=> array(7) 
      { 
      ["contextLink"]=> string(71) "http://animals.nationalgeographic.com/animals/mammals/african-elephant/" 
      ["height"]=> int(450) ["width"]=> int(600) 
      ["byteSize"]=> int(55348) 
      ["thumbnailLink"]=> string(111) "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT8395mqQZUPd2pxSPO7OEPwmjdp5KqtHCRaKzJgcMW_g5mwcEetosfmKU" ["thumbnailHeight"]=> int(101) 
      ["thumbnailWidth"]=> int(135) 
      } 
 }
```

I stored the "items" in an array, and can output the title, link, and description (snippet) using the following code:

```
$googlearray= $js['items'];

    $z=0;
    foreach ($googlearray as $finallist)
    {
     $z++;

    echo $z.": <a href=\"{$finallist['link']}\"><font color ='blue'>{$finallist['title']}</font></a>".": "."$newline"."$newline".$finallist['snippet'].$newline.$newline;

    }
```

Is it possible to display the actual images on the webpage, rather than just links to the images?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display the image change the a-tag img-tag and use the link as the src-attribute. So something like `<img src=\"{$finallist['link']}\" />` should do the trick if I understood your question right.

Comment: Thanks @Emil, this works, now I need to change the size on the images :)

Comment: Do you want it in a fixed width or height? If you just add one of the attributes most web browsers (sometimes internet explorer 7 and earlier doesn't) will auto scale. So if you do a `<img src=\"{$finallist['link']}\" width=\"250px\" />` it will autoscale the height and you can get i.e. 3 pictures on each row. Of course you can change the width to height and get the same effect but height-wise. Also you can change the width size into percentages or any number you want to use.